# Sprite collisions in android andengine

Tags: android, collision-detection, sprite, andengine, collision

I'm developing a simple game by andengine.
I have 10 balls which are moving randomly on screen.i'm importing the balls as picture in sprites.if they move at the same coordinate , they  pass though their own insides.but i want: if they move at the same coodirnates ,they should change their directions.so they cannot pass through their insides.how can i do that?

```
   private Runnable mStartCircle = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        int i = circleNumber++;
        Scene scene = Level1Activity.this.mEngine.getScene();
        float startY = -64.0f;
        float startX = randomNumber.nextFloat()*(CAMERA_WIDTH-70.0f);
        float a= randomNumber.nextFloat()*(CAMERA_WIDTH-70.0f);
        circles[i] = new Sprite(startX, startY, textRegCircle[i]);
        circles[i].registerEntityModifier(
                (IEntityModifier) new SequenceEntityModifier (
                            new MoveModifier(10.0f, circles[i].getX(),  a, 
                                    circles[i].getY(),CAMERA_HEIGHT+64.0f)));
        }
        scene.getLastChild().attachChild(circles[i]);
        if (circleNumber < 10){
            mHandler.postDelayed(mStartCircle,1000);
        }
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

Each object(ball) requires a bounding box, or in your case a bounding circle, which is equal to the size of your sprite.

When the game updates and any balls position changes, you have to test for collisions.

Circle to circle collision testing is the simplest type to do.
if distance between (ball1.pos + ball2.pos) is less than (ball1.radius + ball2.radius) = collision.

You then handle the collision by reversing the velocities or calculating new momentums or something. (You also need to move the objects apart so they are no longer colliding)

Answer (score 0):

**Just apply a physical connector between balls:**

so it will collide and bounce back.

```
final FixtureDef boxFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0.1f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
final Body ballBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, circles[i],BodyType.DynamicBody, boxFixtureDef);
this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(circles[i], ballBody, true, true));
this.mScene.attachChild(circles[i]);
```